# how to bulid a stored procedure in wampServer

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, wampserver

i wrote a stored procedure in a txt file but i don't know how to apply this stored procedure in the server .i created my tables. but again i don't know the steps that i have to take in orded to use the stored procedure.

my stored procedure:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE findHorse @horseName varchar(15) 
AS 
SELECT *
 FROM horse 
WHERE horseName =@horseName
```

i know that if i wante to execute it i use

```
exec findHorse
```

all what i need are : 1. how to create it in mySql. //steps 2.where should i put exec findHorse in order to execute it //steps

Answer (score 0):

It's best to install a database management tool. If you have PHP installed as well you could choose PHPMyAdmin. You can execute this statement just like other sql statement to create the procedure.

Calling stored procedures is usually done in the application that needs them. To be more precise, you usually write a stored procedure if you need them, which means you already have an application for them. Just like you can have a website executing queries to retreive the right data, it could execute stored procedures as well. It seems odd that you have a stored procedure but do not know when to call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpMyAdmin instead of MySQL workbench, you can use the syntax below, without using the `begin` and `end` statements:

```
create procedure procedure_name()
//sql commands ;
```

Comment: Why do you state that this syntax is only working in phpMyAdmin?